# Most pythonic way to express a variable that switches exclusively through two 'named' values

Tags: python, coding-style, readability

I have a iteration that is quite complicated, and each time through the loop, I have need for a 'parameter' that effects the work done in the loop. Basically, I have been doing the following:

```
CLOSE_SIDE = 0
FAR_SIDE = 1

....

while (...):
    if (side == CLOSE_SIDE):
        ....
    else if (side == FAR_SIDE):
        ....

    ....

    side = FAR_SIDE if (side == CLOSE_SIDE) else CLOSE_SIDE
```

I realize I could just use a boolean, but I feel like that reduced the readability and obviousness of what I'm doing. I would like the two states to be 'named'. Also the assignment, though compact, feels very clunky. And doing a whole if statement:

```
if side == CLOSE_SIDE:
    side = FAR_SIDE
else if side == FAR_SIDE:
    side = CLOSE_SIDE
```

feels equally as clunky.

What is the best way to approach this? It's more of a stylistic problem than anything. Would like some opinions from the community

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of naming the two values, you could choose an appropriate name for a `bool` variable and switch it between `True` and `False`:

```
while (...):
    if far:
        ....
    else:
        ....

    ....

    far = not far
```

Answer (score 4):

If the question is mostly about style, the CleanestSolution(tm) is isolate the flip-logic in a function:

```
 side = switch_side(side)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CLOSE_SIDE = -1
FAR_SIDE = 1

# change sides
side = -side
```

Answer (score 1):

Not that it changes much, but to switch between two integers, there is this common idiom:

```
side = CLOSE_SIDE + FAR_SIDE - side
```

Answer (score 0):

Prepend the boolean name with `IS_` or `ON_`, so that its meaning becomes obvious:

```
ON_FAR_SIDE = True

while (...):
    if ON_FAR_SIDE:
        ....
    else:
        # Must be on near side
        ....

    # Switch sides
    ON_FAR_SIDE = not ON_FAR_SIDE
```

The important part is choosing a good variable name.